Unable to connect Keyclaok to external Infinispan
I am trying to connect keycloak with external infinispan. When I run Infinspan I am able to start the server and able to connect to console. The cache required by Keycloak are also created. But when I am starting keycloak I am getting error **"SecurityException: ISPN000287: Unauthorized access: subject 'null' lacks 'LIFECYCLE' permission"
In Security under authorization I have specified the required subject and role but still getting the error.
Keyclaok version: 25.0.1
Infinispan version: 15.0.1
Attached are the cache-ispn.xml file which is passed as a config-file to Keycloak
And For Infinspan I am using infinispan-xsite.xml
Start Infinspan using the command : bin\server.bat -c infinispan-xsite.xml
Start Keyclaok using command: bin\kc.bat start --https-certificate-file=C://Users//Nitiin-O//keycloak.crt --https-certificate-key-file=C://Users//Nitiin-O//keycloak.key --hostname=myapp.com --optimized --cache-config-file=cache-ispn.xml --verbose
Added authorization in Security tag for cache-ispn.xml.
Not sure why the subject is null since I have mentioned the subject and roles in Global security configuration
cache-ispn.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2019 Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates
  ~ and other contributors as indicated by the @author tags.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:15.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-15.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:15.0">

    <cache-container name="keycloak">
        <!--security>
            <authorization enabled="true"/>
         </security-->
         <security>
            <authorization>
                <identity-role-mapper/>
                <role name="user" permissions="LIFECYCLE"/>
                <role name="admin" permissions="ALL BULK_READ WRITE"/>
                <role name="reader" permissions="READ" />
                <role name="writer" permissions="WRITE" />
                <role name="supervisor" permissions="READ WRITE EXEC"/>
            </authorization>
            </security>
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <local-cache name="realms" simple-cache="true">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <security>
                <authorization/>
             </security>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="users" simple-cache="true">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <security>
                <authorization/>
             </security>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="sessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="sessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="127.0.0.1" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="user" password="pass" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
  
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="authenticationSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="127.0.0.1" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="user" password="pass" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="offlineSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="127.0.0.1" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="user" password="pass" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="clientSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="clientSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="127.0.0.1" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="user" password="pass" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="offlineClientSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="127.0.0.1" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="user" password="pass" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="loginFailures" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="loginFailures"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="127.0.0.1" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="user" password="pass" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <local-cache name="authorization" simple-cache="true">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <security>
                <authorization/>
             </security>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <replicated-cache name="work">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="work"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="127.0.0.1" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="user" password="pass" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </replicated-cache>
        <local-cache name="keys" simple-cache="true">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <expiration max-idle="3600000"/>
            <security>
                <authorization/>
             </security>
            <memory max-count="1000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="actionTokens" owners="2">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="actionTokens"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="127.0.0.1" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="user" password="pass" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                    
                </security>
            </remote-store>
            <expiration max-idle="-1" lifespan="-1" interval="300000"/>
            <memory max-count="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>


infinispan-xsite.xml
<infinispan
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:15.0 https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-15.0.xsd
                            urn:infinispan:server:15.0 https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-server-15.0.xsd
                            urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups-5.3.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:15.0"
      xmlns:ispn="urn:infinispan:config:15.0"
      xmlns:server="urn:infinispan:server:15.0">

   <jgroups>
      <!--
      This configuration demonstrates cross-site replication on a single host and uses IP multicast for discovery.

      To use this configuration, do the following:
      
      * Open terminal in $ISPN_HOME.
      * Copy the server/ directory to server2/.
      * Open a terminal and run: ./bin/server.sh -c infinispan-xsite.xml
      * Open another terminal and run: ./bin/server.sh -c infinispan-xsite.xml -s server2 -Dinfinispan.site.name=site2 -o 100 -Djgroups.mcast_port=46656
      * Check server logs for the following message: "[org.infinispan.XSITE] ISPN000439: Received new x-site view: [site1, site2]"
      -->
      <stack name="bridge" extends="tcp">
         <MPING mcast_port="${jgroups.bridge.mcast_port:47655}"
                ispn:stack.combine="COMBINE"
                xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
         />
      </stack>
      <stack name="local" extends="udp">
         <relay.RELAY2 site="${infinispan.site.name:site1}"
                       max_site_masters="${infinispan.site.max_relay_nodes:1}"
                       xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"/>
         <remote-sites default-stack="bridge">
            <remote-site name="${infinispan.site.name:site1}"/>
         </remote-sites>
      </stack>
   </jgroups>

   <cache-container name="keycloak" statistics="true">
      <transport cluster="${infinispan.cluster.name:ISPN}" stack="${infinispan.cluster.stack:local}" node-name="${infinispan.node.name:}"/>
      <security>
            <authorization>
                <role name="admin" permissions="ALL"/>
                <role name="user" permissions="LIFECYCLE"/>
            </authorization>
         </security>
      <replicated-cache name="work">
        <encoding>
            <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
        </encoding>
        
    </replicated-cache>
    
    
    <distributed-cache name="sessions">
        <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            
    </distributed-cache>
    
    <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions">
        <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            
    </distributed-cache>
    
    <distributed-cache name="clientSessions">
        <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            
    </distributed-cache>
    
    <distributed-cache name="offlineSessions">
        <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            
    </distributed-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions">
        <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            
    </distributed-cache>
    
    
    <distributed-cache name="actionTokens">
        <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            
    </distributed-cache>
    
    <distributed-cache name="loginFailures">
        <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            
    </distributed-cache>
   </cache-container>

   <server xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:15.0">
       
      <interfaces>
         <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${infinispan.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
         </interface>
      </interfaces>

      <socket-bindings default-interface="public" port-offset="${infinispan.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
         <socket-binding name="default" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}"/>
      </socket-bindings>
      
      

      <security>
         <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="default">
               <!-- Uncomment to enable TLS on the realm -->
               <!-- server-identities>
                  <ssl>
                     <keystore path="server.pfx"
                               password="password" alias="server"
                               generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                  </ssl>
               </server-identities-->
               <properties-realm/>
            </security-realm>
         </security-realms>
      </security>

      <!--endpoints socket-binding="default" security-realm="default" /-->
      <endpoints socket-binding="default" security-realm="default">
          <endpoint>
          <hotrod-connector name="hotrod">
            <authentication>
              <sasl mechanisms="DIGEST DIGEST-SHA-256"
                    server-name="infinispan" />
            </authentication>
          </hotrod-connector>
          <rest-connector name="rest"/>
        </endpoint>
    </endpoints>
   </server>
</infinispan>


